# could not find location of Jmeter script in Taurus tool runner

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines, taurus

I followed the guide https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexandreGattiker.jmeter-tasks to trigger Jmeter script in Azure pipeline.

In Taurus Configuration YAML of Taurus tool runner, I defined a YAML as following
[TaurusConfigurationYaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHZj7.png)
[Release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH4CU.png)

The problem is that it could not find location at path: Blazedemo.jmx in running Taurus

I tried to change value of script to **\Blazedemo.jmx it does not work

The question is that where it find Blazedemo.jmx. I push Blazedemo.jmx into my azure repo already in root

Please give me advice.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check if you have checked out the `Blazedemo.jmx` file first. Please add the variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. After that trigger a new build to capture and share the complete logs here so we can analyze and give the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dmitri T. I fixed my issue. In Download Artifacts, it shown D:\a\r1\a_dev-branch - CI\drop\bin\Release\BlazeDemo.jmx. So I just change the path of jmx file in Taurus tool runner as following

execution:
- scenario:
    script: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)_dev-branch - CI\drop\bin\Release\BlazeDemo.jmx
  concurrency: 30
  hold-for: 300s
  ramp-up: 30s

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Blazedemo.jmx` file at the same location where your [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) config file lives you can use just `script: Blazedemo.jmx`, there is no need to go for [Ant-style filesets](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

Also you can omit the step of JMeter installation, [Taurus can download and install JMeter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Location-Auto-Installation) on its own

More information:

- [Install and run JMeter and Taurus testing tools.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexandreGattiker.jmeter-tasks)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)